# Why is CollectionView.CollectionChanged protected?

Tags: wpf, collections

I want to monitor changes to a CollectionView but the CollectionChanged event is protected. How should I do this? Surely there must be a way to subscribe to this event - the list controls must do this somehow.

I can cast SourceCollection to INotifyCollectionChanged and add an event there, but that seems unneccesarily messy.

Comment: Well, apparently it was intentionally "hidden" from public access... I don't know why exactly, but what you're trying to do is probably the exact thing they wanted to prevent ;)

Answer (score 5):

> ... the list controls must do this somehow.
>
> I can cast SourceCollection to INotifyCollectionChanged and add an event there, but that
>   seems unneccesarily messy.

In fact, that's exactly how the list controls do it. This is from ItemsControl's source code (found via http://www.dotnetframework.org/):

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged)_items).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnItemCollectionChanged);
```

You are probably meant to expose your CollectionViews as the interface, *ICollectionView*, which itself inherits INotifyCollectionChanged as well as providing CollectionView properties like CurrentItem.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using an ObservableCollection instead?

Comment: Because I am filtering the collection.

Comment: ...and need CurrentItem functionality so CollectionView make sense.